# How to get select box option value in a input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

Here is my code:

```
<select name="art_type">
    <option value="ra">Research Article</option>
    <option value="rea">Review Article</option>
    <option value="re">Reviews</option>
    <option value="op">Opinions</option>
    <option value="le">Letters to the Editor</option>
</select>

<input style="border: none;" type="text" id="get_id_val" value="">
```

So whatever value user selects from the select box that value should be entered in the textbox.
 How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $idval = $('#get_id_val');
    $('select[name="art_type"]').change(function(){
        $idval.val($(this).val())
    }).triggerHandler('change')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Kbwm/)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to style the select box, I mean whenever one option is selected, it must follow the width. In the above options Letters to the Editor size is more, but the other options sizes are small so how to make it follow its size width?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
   $("#get_id_val").val( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select[name=art_type]').on('change', function () {
    var select = $(this).find('option:selected').val()
    $('#get_id_val').val(select)
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/djaJx/)